# Pandas 'bool object is not callable'

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with several columns, and I'm trying to group it in respect to a column and sort it according to another column.
If I apply groupby() like this:

```
data.groupby(columnA)
```

it doesn't spit out any errors, yet if I try to sort it like this:

```
data.groupby(columnA).sort(coulmnB)
```

it gives me

```
TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable
```

I don't have any bool objects in any of the columns, and totally clueless about why this error is occuring.
How would I solve this problem? If I'm totally doing it wrong, what's another way to group, and sort a DataFrame according to two different columns?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sort_values.html):

EDIT: But better is using [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sort_values.html) only, [see Andy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37782053/2901002).

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'columnA':[1,2,3,3,1,2],
                     'columnB':[7,5,6,1,2,4],
                     'columnC':[7,8,9,1,8,0]})

print (data)
   columnA  columnB  columnC
0        1        7        7
1        2        5        8
2        3        6        9
3        3        1        1
4        1        2        8
5        2        4        0

print (data.groupby('colA').apply(lambda x:x.sort_values('colB')).reset_index(drop=True))
   colA  colB  colC
0     1     2     8
1     1     7     7
2     2     4     0
3     2     5     8
4     3     1     1
5     3     6     9

print (data.groupby('colA').apply(lambda x:x.sort_values('colC')).reset_index(drop=True))
   colA  colB  colC
0     1     7     7
1     1     2     8
2     2     4     0
3     2     5     8
4     3     1     1
5     3     6     9
```

[`sort`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort.html) is **DEPRECATED**.

but if use [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) get error:

```
print (data.groupby('colA').sort_values('colB'))
```

> AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'sort_values' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method

Answer (score 4):

Since you want to sort by columnA first followed by columnB, you can do this using [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) only:

```
# using jezrael's example
In [11]: data.sort_values(["columnA", "columnB"])
Out[11]:
   columnA  columnB  columnC
4        1        2        8
0        1        7        7
5        2        4        0
1        2        5        8
3        3        1        1
2        3        6        9

In [12]: data.sort_values(["columnA", "columnB"], ascending=[True, False])
Out[12]:
   columnA  columnB  columnC
0        1        7        7
4        1        2        8
1        2        5        8
5        2        4        0
2        3        6        9
3        3        1        1
```

---

Note: `sort` is an (boolean) attribute of groupby, that's why it can't be called:

```
In [21]: data.groupby("columnA").sort
Out[21]: True

In [22]: data.groupby("columnA", sort=False).sort
Out[22]: False

In [23]: True()
TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable
```

You can see what this does internally with the following example:

```
In [31]: df = pd.DataFrame([["b", 1], ["a", 2]], columns=["A", "B"])

In [32]: df.groupby("A").sum()
Out[32]:
   B
A
a  2
b  1

In [33]: df.groupby("A", sort=False).sum()
Out[33]:
   B
A
b  1
a  2
```

Note: This behavior/ordering is not guaranteed, it just means that pandas won't go out of its way to order the groupby key... e.g. for some index types it may sort:

```
In [34]: df.groupby("B", sort=False).sum()
Out[34]:
   A
B
1  b
2  a
```